# AndroidStudio shows files in the project structure which are not in CMakeLists.txt. How to fix?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I have shared C++ module, that contains logic for iOS, macOS and Android. When I include this project into Android Studio. It shows all the files in the Project Structure(iOS and macOS as well). How to make Android Studio to shows only files,that are in CMakeLists.txt.

Here is my structure:

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.19.1"
        }
    }
```

[image]

As you can see on the screenshots there Apple related files as well as Xcode project files